nav2 amcl robot local costmap offset from global costmap
I have a problem using nav2 and amcl on a gazebo-simulated robot in which the odom frame and local costmap drift as the robot moves. Please see the screenshot below.
Here is the environment for context:

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
Gazebo Fortress
Cyclone DDS
DiffDrive plugin

Even if I disable transform publishing in AMCL, the robot pose in RVIZ accumulates errors relative to the true pose in Gazebo. The error seems to increase primarily during robot rotation movements. Initially, I thought this must be due to incorrect odometry from the diffdrive plugin, such as invalid wheel separation or wheel slip, but I have repeatedly verified these settings and am unable to find the source of the error. What are the most likely causes?

Robot URDF:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="robot_0"
  xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Define robot constants -->
  <xacro:property name="base_radius" value="0.6" />
  <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.4" />

  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.2" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_ygap" value="${wheel_width / 2}" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_zoff" value="0.15" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_xoff" value="0.0" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_yoff" value="0.3" />

  <xacro:property name="caster_radius" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="caster_xoff" value="0.3" />
  <xacro:property name="caster_yoff" value="0.3" />
  <xacro:property name="caster_zoff" value="${wheel_radius + wheel_zoff - caster_radius}" />

  <xacro:property name="laser_radius" value="0.05" />
  <xacro:property name="laser_height" value="0.3" />

  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system"
      name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">
      <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
      <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
      <wheel_separation>${(wheel_yoff + wheel_ygap) * 2}</wheel_separation>
  <wheel_radius>${wheel_radius}</wheel_radius>
      <max_linear_acceleration>1.0</max_linear_acceleration>
      <odom_publish_frequency>10</odom_publish_frequency>
      <topic>/model/robot_0/cmd_vel</topic>
      <tf_topic>/model/robot_0/tf</tf_topic>
      <frame_id>odom</frame_id>
      <child_frame_id>base_link</child_frame_id>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-pose-publisher-system"
      name="ignition::gazebo::systems::PosePublisher">
      <publish_link_pose>false</publish_link_pose>
      <publish_nested_model_pose>true</publish_nested_model_pose>
      <use_pose_vector_msg>true</use_pose_vector_msg>
      <update_frequency>10</update_frequency>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-joint-state-publisher-system"
      name="ignition::gazebo::systems::JointStatePublisher">
      <joint_name>right_wheel_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>left_wheel_joint</joint_name>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Define some commonly used intertial properties  -->
  <xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="m w h d">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${pi/2}" />
      <mass value="${m}" />
  <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (h*h + d*d)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(m/12) * (w*w + d*d)}"
    iyz="0.0" izz="${(m/12) * (w*w + h*h)}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
  <mass value="${m}" />
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}"
        iyz="0" izz="${(m/2) * (r*r)}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="sphere_inertia" params="m r">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${m}" />
  <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" iyz="0.0"
    izz="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!-- Robot Base -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${base_radius}" length="${base_height}" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="Cyan">
        <color rgba="0 0 1.0 1.0" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${base_radius}" length="${base_height}" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="15" r="${base_radius}" h="${base_height}" />
  </link>


  <!-- Robot Footprint -->
  <link name="base_footprint">
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0" w="0" d="0" h="0" />
  </link>
  <joint name="footprint_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="base_footprint" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${-(wheel_radius-wheel_zoff)}" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>


  <!-- Wheels -->
  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix y_reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="Gray">
          <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0" />
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}" />
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>100</mu>
              <mu2>100</mu2>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>

      <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.1" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}" />
    </link>

    <joint name="${prefix}_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link" />
  <child link="${prefix}_link" />
      <origin xyz="${wheel_xoff} ${y_reflect*(wheel_yoff + wheel_ygap)} ${-wheel_zoff}" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
      <limit
        effort="20"
        velocity="5" />
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:wheel prefix="left_wheel" y_reflect="1" />
  <xacro:wheel prefix="right_wheel" y_reflect="-1" />

  <xacro:macro name="caster" params="prefix x_reflect y_reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_caster">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <sphere radius="${caster_radius}" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="green">
          <color rgba="0 1.0 0 1.0" />
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <sphere radius="${caster_radius}" />
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
<joint name="${prefix}_caster_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="base_link" />
      <child link="${prefix}_caster" />
  <origin xyz="${caster_xoff * x_reflect} ${caster_yoff * y_reflect} ${-caster_zoff}"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
    <gazebo reference="${prefix}_caster">
      <collision>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>0</mu>
              <mu2>0</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:caster prefix="front_left" x_reflect="1" y_reflect="1" />
  <xacro:caster prefix="front_right" x_reflect="1" y_reflect="-1" />
  <xacro:caster prefix="rear_left" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="1" />
  <xacro:caster prefix="rear_right" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="-1" />


  <link name="orientation_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_radius*1.1} 0.1 0.05" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="cyan">
        <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0" />
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_radius*1.1} 0.1 0.05" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="0.01" w="${base_radius*1.1}" d="0.1" h="0.05" />
  </link>

  <joint name="orientation_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="orientation_link" />
    <origin xyz="${base_radius/2 - 0.1*base_radius/2} 0 ${base_height/2}" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <!-- LIDAR -->
  <link name="lidar_link">
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.125" r="${laser_radius}" h="${laser_height}" />

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${laser_radius}" length="${laser_height}" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${laser_radius}" length="${laser_height}" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="lidar_link" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 1.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference="lidar_link">
    <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>
      <topic>
        scan</topic>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <gz_frame_id>lidar_link</gz_frame_id>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>100</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14159</min_angle>
            <max_angle>3.14159</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>1</samples>
            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.08</min>
          <max>10.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>
        true</visualize>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>

Nav2 Params:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: false
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.01
    update_min_d: 0.01
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan
    always_reset_initial_pose: false

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.1
      movement_time_allowance: 20.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.02
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: -0.2
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.2
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.5
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.2
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 30
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 30
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.01
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.01
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics:
        [
          "RotateToGoal",
          "Oscillation",
          "ObstacleFootprint",
          "PathAlign",
          "PathDist",
          "GoalDist",
        ]
      PathAlign.scale: 8.0
      PathDist.scale: 24.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.2
      GoalDist.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 10.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      ObstacleFootprint.scale: 100.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 10.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 8
      height: 8
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.6
      footprint_padding: 0.1
      plugins: ["inflation_layer", "static_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.6
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.6
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      footprint_padding: 0.1
      plugins: ["static_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "config/map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 0.5
    min_rotational_vel: 0.2
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.2, 0.0, 0.5]
    min_velocity: [-0.2, 0.0, -0.5]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0


This turned out to be an issue with use_sim_time. I thought use_sim_time was True, since it was set to True in the params yaml file, but the nav2 launch file was overwriting it to False. The solution is to pass the argument "use_sim_time": "True" to the nav2 launch file. For example:
    nav2_bringup_share = get_package_share_directory("nav2_bringup")
    nav2_bringup = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(nav2_bringup_share + "/launch/bringup_launch.py"),
        launch_arguments={
            "params_file": os.path.join(pkg_share, "config/nav2_params.yaml"),
            "map": os.path.join(pkg_share, "config/map.yaml"),
            "use_sim_time": "True",
        }.items(),
    )

